# how to use a different name for my class property than the sql column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

For example, if I wanted my class property to be named like this for a laugh:

```
class Product
{
   [Key]
   int ProductID {get;set;}

   [Required]
   string TitleTOTHEMAX {get;set;}
}
```

My Sql table has 2 columns "ProductID" and "Title", how do I tell the class's property to map itself to "Title" column considering the "TitleTOTHEMAX" column does not exist :)

Comment: check here for some samples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this but one is to specify a Column attribute on the property.

> [Column("Title")]

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591583#TableColumn) for more information

Comment: using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use the same property name as my SQL field. If you want to change the display name just use the [Display] attribute on the property

Comment: It's not up to me unfortunately :) I like it to represent what's in the database, but sometimes the cookie doesn't crumble that way... It gets me all OCD

Answer (score 0):

You should use Fluent Api with those kind of configuration.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .Property(x => x.TitleTOTHEMAX )
    .HasColumnName("Title")
}
```